# SQL select and count at the same time

Tags: sql, select, count

I am trying to select all from stuff and count the total amount of items in morestuff where stuff id = morestuff id.

```
select *,
    COUNT(morestuff.items) as total
from stuff,
    morestuff
where stuff.id = '{$id}'
    and morestuff.id = stuff.id
```

Obviously there is something wrong with my query, can anyone help?

Comment: Aggregate functions like `Count` require a `group by`.  Instead of trying to troubleshoot this via PHP, why not hit the DB directly and track down errors from there first?  That might help you understand why this query doesn't work.

Comment: @Marc - There is no such requirement. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table` for example, is valid.

Comment: @Chris, point taken.  I was referring to using `count` with other non-aggregate fields.

Comment: While you are executing your SQL in a PHP script it has nothing to do with PHP itself, you should try to only tag what is relevant.  In this case "SQL"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be another option:

```
select
  *, (
    select count(*)
    from morestuff
    where morestuff.id = stuff.id
      ) as total
from stuff
where id = '{$id}'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT s.*, coalesce(ms.Count, 0) as Count
FROM stuff s
left outer join (
    select id, count(*) as Count
    from morestuff
    group by id
) ms on s.id = ms.id
WHERE s.id='{$id}'
```